# Badge iOS application without running the app or sending a push notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

I have a task manager app, and I want the app icon to show badges for the number of tasks due today. I know you can use

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
```

to badge, but the user would have to open the app. I know you can set it up so a notification is sent on a certain date, but all I want is the badge. I don't want a notification with a message sent.

Comment: `UILocalNotification` can be configured to update the badge without showing a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UILocalNotification` can be configured to only set the badge of the application, if you leave `alertBody` as `nil`, and only fill in the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` (and `fireDate`) properties.